# Find the diagonals in an array that is a representation of a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I converted my 2d array to a 1d array. For example:  (Starts at 0, not 1);
00 01 02 03 04 
05 06 07 08 09 
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24

was converted to a 1d array.
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4.....23, 24].

I am now attempting to create a function that finds every spot that is "connected" or next to a certain element in the array. This includes elements that are diagonal from it. So using the above 2d array, if I want an array of elements that are connected to 0, I expect the function to return the array
[1, 5, 6].

The trouble I am having is finding the diagonals. This is my JS code for the array that should be returned.

```
var poss = [Number(num+1),Number(num-1),Number(num+col),Number(num-col),Number((num+col) + 1),Number((num+col) - 1),Number((num-col) + 1),Number((num-col) - 1)];
```

This returns [1, 5, 6, 4]. 
I have code that excludes negative numbers. However, 4 should not be there.
I realize this is because this is an edge case and it isn't registering as out of bounds because it isn't a negative number. Is there a formula of some sort that will find the elements connected to it diagonally ? Remember I am using a 1d array. This program also run independently of the array size. So this will also have to work for boards that are 4x4 or 5x4. So using the row and num fields is ideal.

Comment: I realized one mistake I made. I used rows instead of columns for calculating the surrounding numbers. I have changed this and it did fix some errors, but I am still having trouble find the diagonals. I am taking an  approach of using an if statement to find whether or not a number is an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

I've seemed to have figured it out. At the very least, I've passed all of my test cases. I am sure that this is not the most simply, elegant, or efficient way. More test cases are probably needed. I made sure it is calculated independent of the number of columns and rows. Here is the huge if statement I used.

```
var x = poss[i]
if((Number(num) % col == 0 && Number(num-1) == Number(x)) || 
 (Number(num+1) % col == 0 && Number(num+1) == Number(x)) || 
 ((Number(num) % col == 0 || Number(num+1) % col == 0) && (Number((num-col) -1) == Number(x))) || 
 ((Number(num) % col == 0 || Number(num+1) % col == 0) && (Number((num+col) -1) == Number(x))) ||
 ((Number(num) % col == 0 || Number(num+1) % col == 0) && (Number((num-col) +1) == Number(x))) || 
 ((Number(num) % col == 0 || Number(num+1) % col == 0) && (Number((num+col) +1) == Number(x)))) 
{//exclude number from results}
```

The variable num is the number on the array that you are currently searching neighbors for. Variable x is one of the possible neighbors.

Feel free to post another idea.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution to this issue, it should be easy to read and understand and I added some comments on it as well.

```
var cols = 5;
var rows = 5;

function connectedPoints(point) {
  var connectedPoints = [];

  // First test if the point is on an edge
  var topEdge = point/cols < 1;
  var leftEdge = point%cols == 0;
  var rightEdge = point%cols == cols-1;
  var bottomEdge = point/cols >= rows-1;

  // Add points that are above the point
  if (!topEdge) {
    if (!leftEdge) {
      connectedPoints.push(returnIfNotNegative(point-cols-1));
    }

    connectedPoints.push(returnIfNotNegative(point-cols));

    if (!rightEdge) {
      connectedPoints.push(returnIfNotNegative(point-cols+1));
    }
  }

  // Add points that are to the left or right of the point
  if (!leftEdge) {
    connectedPoints.push(returnIfNotNegative(point-1));
  }
  if (!rightEdge) {
    connectedPoints.push(returnIfNotNegative(point+1));
  }

  // Add points that are below the point
  if (!bottomEdge) {
    if (!leftEdge) {
      connectedPoints.push(returnIfNotNegative(point+cols-1));
    }

    connectedPoints.push(returnIfNotNegative(point+cols));

    if (!rightEdge) {
      connectedPoints.push(returnIfNotNegative(point+cols+1));
    }
  }

  console.log(connectedPoints);
}

function returnIfNotNegative(point) {
  if (point < 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return point;
}

connectedPoints(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using position instead of value. This will simplify things.

You can have another function to get position of value.

```js
var arr = [
  [00, 01, 02, 03, 04],
  [05, 06, 07, 08, 09],
  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
]

function getNeighbours(x, y) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
    for (var j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
      if (arr[i] && arr[i][j]) {
        if (!(x === i && y === j))
          result.push(arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getNeighbours(0, 0));
console.log(getNeighbours(3, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with the arrays it's important to move as much computation outside the inner loop as possible. My approach was to find the start positions of the left column in each row and then iterating over the column range.

```js
var arr = [
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
  5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
  10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
  15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
  20, 21, 22, 23, 24
]

function getNeighbours(col, row)
{
  var w = 5;
  
  var start = (row > 0 ? row * w - w : row * w) + (col > 0 ? col - 1 : col);
  var rowSpan = ((row > 0 ? 2 : 1) + (row < (w - 1) ? 1 : 0)) * w;
  var colSpan = (col > 0 ? 2 : 1) + (col < (w -1) ? 1 : 0);
  
  var center = col + row * w;
  var result = [];
  for (var r = start; r < start + rowSpan; r += w)
    for (var i = r; i < r + colSpan; i++)
      if (!(i === center))
         result.push(arr[i]);
      
  return result;
}


console.log(getNeighbours(0,0));
console.log(getNeighbours(3,3));
console.log(getNeighbours(3,4));
console.log(getNeighbours(4,3));
console.log(getNeighbours(4,4));
 
/*
[1, 5, 6]
[12, 13, 14, 17, 19, 22, 23, 24]
[17, 18, 19, 22, 24]
[13, 14, 18, 23, 24]
[18, 19, 23]
*/
```